# On Android, how can i write a code that allow us to click an operating button on the first page get the result of calculation on another next page?

Tags: java, android

for example: on current page we have 2 Texteditors. We enter numbers to each of the field and then click a operator button to see the result that will be shown on the next page. ^^ help...

Answer (score 2):

When you start a new activity via an Intent, then you can put extra data to that intent which can then be retrieved in the called activity.

Example:

First Activity:

```
Intent i = new Intent(CatalogueOverviewActivity.this, CatalogueStartActivity.class);
i.putExtra(CatalogueStartActivity.EXTRA_CATALOGUENUMBER, pagenumber);
startActivity(i);
```

Second Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    int catNr = extras.getInt(EXTRA_CATALOGUENUMBER);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the values from the two EditText fields.
2. Calculate the result.
3. Send the result to the next activity by including it as an extra in the intent with `putExtra()`.
4. In the next activity, retrieve the result from the intent.

Answer (score 0):

**You can define a variable as**

```
 public static int integerTest;
```

**and then use it anywhere in application by just using its class name.**